# How to deal the multipage pdf file with tess4j

Tags: tess4j

I am using tess4j to recognize the image file.

```
Pix pix = Leptonica1.pixRead(image.getPath());
        TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIInit3(tessBaseAPI, tessDataPath, "eng");
        TessAPI1.TessBaseAPISetImage2(tessBaseAPI, pix);
//        TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIProcessPages(tessBaseAPI,image.getPath(),"",0,null);

        PointerByReference pixa = null;
        PointerByReference blockids = null;
        Boxa boxa = TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIGetComponentImages(tessBaseAPI, ITessAPI.TessPageIteratorLevel.RIL_TEXTLINE, 1, pixa, blockids);
```

For multiple page tiff files only the Boxa information in the first page can be returned by TessBaseAPIGetComponentImages().
If I use `TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIProcessPages(tessBaseAPI,image.getPath(),"",0,null);`
 only the last page information can be returned.
So how can I deal with the recognized information page by page for multiple pages?

Thanks.

Comment: did you find an answer for this?